# Not able to test the transaction using test account in Authorize.net

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, authorize.net

In iPhone simulator, i  have  registerd and also logged in successfully using  authorize.net . But i am not able to perform transaction. Codes for MobileDeviceLoginRequest and createTransaction as in below.

-(void)loginToGateway
{

MobileDeviceLoginRequest *mobileDeviceLoginRequest = [MobileDeviceLoginRequest 
mobileDeviceLoginRequest];

mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name = @"*********";

mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = @"***********";

mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.mobileDeviceId = [OpenUDID value];

[AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_TEST];

AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];

[an setDelegate:self];
[an mobileDeviceLoginRequest:mobileDeviceLoginRequest];

}

-(void)mobileDeviceLoginSucceeded:(MobileDeviceLoginResponse *)response
{

```
 sessionToken = [response.sessionToken retain];

 [self createTransaction];
```

}
-(void)createTransaction
{

```
AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];
[an setDelegate:self];
CreditCardType *creditCardType = [CreditCardType creditCardType];
creditCardType.cardNumber = @"4111111111111111";
creditCardType.cardCode = @"100";
creditCardType.expirationDate = @"1212";
PaymentType *paymentType = [PaymentType paymentType];
paymentType.creditCard = creditCardType;

ExtendedAmountType *extendedAmountTypeTax = [ExtendedAmountType extendedAmountType];
extendedAmountTypeTax.amount = @"0";
extendedAmountTypeTax.name = @"Tax";

ExtendedAmountType *extendedAmountTypeShipping = [ExtendedAmountType extendedAmountType];
extendedAmountTypeShipping.amount = @"0";
extendedAmountTypeShipping.name = @"Shipping";

LineItemType *lineItem = [LineItemType lineItem];
lineItem.itemName = @"Soda";
lineItem.itemDescription = @"Soda";
lineItem.itemQuantity = @"1";
lineItem.itemPrice = @"1.00";
lineItem.itemID = @"1";

TransactionRequestType *requestType = [TransactionRequestType transactionRequest];
requestType.lineItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:lineItem];
requestType.amount = @"1.00";
requestType.payment = paymentType;
requestType.tax = extendedAmountTypeTax;
requestType.shipping = extendedAmountTypeShipping;
CreateTransactionRequest *request = [CreateTransactionRequest createTransactionRequest];    
request.transactionRequest = requestType;
request.transactionType = AUTH_ONLY;
request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.mobileDeviceId = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.sessionToken = sessionToken;
[an purchaseWithRequest:request];}
```

**mobileDeviceLoginResponse as in below:** // i am getting session also

```
  <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
  <message>
     <code>I00001</code>
     <text>Successful.</text>
```

**createTransactionResponse as in below:**

```
     <code>E00054</code>
     <text>The mobile device is not registered with this merchant account.</text>
```

Comment: If you have to post a wall of code then you did not do enough debugging on your own

Comment: @Dsk:I have a doubt in the above code .Do we need to enter the exact username and password in the method -(void)loginToGateway . Is it secure if we use the password directly in the code?

Comment: @ ArunMak , I am also having same doubt.But ,I have taken the code from their Authorize.net website only. see the below link http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios/

Comment: @Dsk Ya i have also taken the same code.It asks for password to be entered in the code.Is there any other way to do the transaction without the password or do you have any solution?

Comment: @ArunMak : I am using  authorize.net sdk only , but till now i  did not get any prompt  for  Login ID and Password .I just hardcoded everything like above code.  Can you explain me how you are getting the prompt.

Comment: @dsk actually we can change the coding to ask in a pop up but it of no use bcos a user doesnt know the merchant account id and password .The code you are using is correct but is it the right thing to enter the password in the code ?

Comment: @ArunMak : I think its not a better way to add password in code , but any how most of the peoples are using like this only.

Comment: @ArunMak : I am not able to test the  transaction process because i am getting error as
"The mobile device is not registered with this merchant account". Do you have any idea?

Comment: @dsk:Yes you have not registered the device in your authorise.net account.You can also do it through your coding .

Comment: @ArunMak : Can u give me a idea do the things without device registration.

Comment: @Dsk:Without device registration you cant make a transaction.You can register your device through coding Or you can add device by logging into  authorize.net account.

Comment: @ArunMak : Yes Arun i have registered and also logged in successfully through code  but while transaction i am getting following message "The mobile device is not registered with this merchant account" .

Comment: @Dsk:Have you registered your device with the correct username and password .Also check whether you made a sandbox account and made as test in coding.

Comment: @ArunMak : Yes i have given correct username and password in code. Firstly i call MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest and then MobileDeviceLoginRequest and then CreateTransactionRequest . I am  using only username and password  in the code but where we need to use the trancation key ?

Comment: @dsk:Without using the transaction key ,you can perform a transaction .No need of using the transaction key.Username and password is enough

Comment: See the below link , any thing i forgot?http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/For-Transaction-Test-account-or-Merchant-account/td-p/36873

Answer (score 0):

Error code E00054 indicates you need to perform a mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest and approve the device in the merchant interface before you can create transactions.

Comment: Initially i have registered my mobile device using test account and then enabled my device in authorize.net website and then logged in  successfully in my app .Is it possible to test the transaction process with my test account ? . Or I need to create merchant account ?.

Comment: @rhldr:I have a doubt  in the above code .Do we need to enter the exact username and password  in the method -(void)loginToGateway .       Is it secure if we use the password directly in the code?

Comment: @ArunMak Your application should prompt the user for their Login ID and Password.  Storing user credentials on a mobile device is never recommended.

Comment: @Dsk The sandbox simulates connections to a merchant account, so you don't need a live production payment gateway account to test transactions.  See the getting started video at http://developer.authorize.net/training/ for more details.

Comment: @rhldr Actually I want to store the merchant account password .Each time I dont want the pop up to appear and ask for a password and username.It is going to be the same merchant every time.